# StackOverflowError during Liberty startup during ApplicationStateManager.fireStarting

Tags: war, websphere-liberty

BLUF: I'm getting a stackoverflow starting my Liberty server with a single war file before it reaches any of my code. I can't debug what is causing the problem. I tried adding trace statements to server.xml but never got files I could interpret (were binary) and trying to Open Log Files had no choices available (greyed out). If anyone has any ideas how to determine what is causing the stack overflow I'd appreciate the help. Thanks in advance. My code does use @Inject but I don't think this is the issue as all works fine if I move code from a separate project/jar into the war project.

Running wlp 17.0.0.1 when starting a single war using shared libraries to jar files in a single directory, I get a StackOverflowError before any of my code is reached (based on setting breakpoints in the RestServicesApplication and any static initializers).

This problem only occurs when some classes have been moved to a separate project and therefore into a separate jar (e.g., moving them back to the war project allows all to run fine).

I've checked that all classes and methods references are public. I'm calling public static methods in the new jar file.

I'm not sure how to figure out the problem as no references to my code are in the ffdc files in the stack traces.

I've verified the needed classes are in the jar file and there are no duplicate classes being referenced.

Essentially, the class in the war file has a call like:

```
public static JSONObject processFuzzyMatch(ID session,
   ID userID, JSONObject request)
   throws ILDException {
   try {
      return NLUFuzzyEntityMatcherFunction.processFuzzyMatch(request);
   } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new ILDException(e);
   }
}
```

and NLUFuzzyEntityMatcherFunction is in the jar file declared as:

```
public static JSONObject processFuzzyMatch(JSONObject request)
  throws Exception
```

Here is an example of the reported problem with the last line repeating (for the stack overflow...)

```
Stack Dump = com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.internal.ApplicationStateManager.fireStarting(ApplicationStateManager.java:33)
    at com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.internal.StateChangeServiceImpl.fireApplicationStarting(StateChangeServiceImpl.java:51)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.preDeployApp(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:376)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployApp(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:403)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.war.internal.WARApplicationHandlerImpl.install(WARApplicationHandlerImpl.java:66)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.StartAction.execute(StartAction.java:141)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.enterState(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:1253)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.run(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:866)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:242)
    at java.io.File.exists(File.java:819)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.kernel.service.utils.FileUtils$3.run(FileUtils.java:88)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.kernel.service.utils.FileUtils$3.run(FileUtils.java:85)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.kernel.service.utils.FileUtils.fileExists(FileUtils.java:85)
    at com.ibm.ws.artifact.loose.internal.LooseArchive$DirEntryInfo.matches(LooseArchive.java:232)
    at com.ibm.ws.artifact.loose.internal.LooseArchive$DirEntryInfo.matches(LooseArchive.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.artifact.loose.internal.LooseArchive.getEntry(LooseArchive.java:782)
    at com.ibm.ws.artifact.overlay.internal.DirectoryBasedOverlayContainerImpl.getEntry(DirectoryBasedOverlayContainerImpl.java:838)
    at com.ibm.ws.adaptable.module.internal.AdaptableContainerImpl.getEntry(AdaptableContainerImpl.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TagLibraryCache.loadWebInfMap(TagLibraryCache.java:613)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TagLibraryCache.loadWebInfMap(TagLibraryCache.java:629)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TagLibraryCache.loadWebInfMap(TagLibraryCache.java:629)
    (above line repeats due to stack overflow)
```

Comment: If you're getting log contents in binary (know as HPEL, High Performance Extensible Logging), look at this IBM KnowldegeCenter topic  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_confHPEL.html to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem on Liberty. The fix to that problem will be available on Liberty 17.0.0.3.

You can use some workarounds:

- I assume you have a folder named WEB-INF within a jar. Change the folder name to something else. That folder name causes the JSP engine to go to the web module's WEB-INF (scanning everything again!), instead of the jar's WEB-INF.
- Try setting the JSP configuration parameter disableTldSearch to true; this may be troublesome if you are using custom tag libraries. With the property set, all your custom TLD files need to be declared in the web.xml.
- Disable CDI; I know this may not be possible for you as you mentioned you are using injections.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I screwed up the project settings for the jar project (likely because I'd copied the pom.xml from the Web project and forgot to change it to jar...). This may have resulted in the screwed up xml file in the /apps folder with an embedded reference to a non-existent war file (see below):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archive>
    <archive targetInArchive="/WEB-INF/lib/ildMicroServices-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar">
        <dir sourceOnDisk="/csnext/ild/ild_framework/ildMicroServices/WebContent" targetInArchive="/"/>
        <dir sourceOnDisk="/csnext/ild/ild_framework/ildMicroServices/target/classes" targetInArchive="/WEB-INF/classes"/>
        <dir sourceOnDisk="/csnext/ild/ild_framework/ildMicroServices/target/test-
classes" targetInArchive="/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    </archive>
    <dir sourceOnDisk="/csnext/ild/ild_framework/ildRESTServices/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources" targetInArchive="/"/>
    <dir sourceOnDisk="/csnext/ild/ild_framework/ildRESTServices/WebContent" targetInArchive="/"/>
    <dir sourceOnDisk="/csnext/ild/ild_framework/ildRESTServices/target/classes" targetInArchive="/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <dir sourceOnDisk="/csnext/ild/ild_framework/ildRESTServices/target/test-classes" targetInArchive="/WEB-INF/classes"/>
</archive>
```

By deleting this embedded archive the problem went away.

I only found this after upgrading from Neon to Oxygen, and 17.0.0.1 to 17.0.0.2 and when setting up the new server using the old server's artifacts, I noticed the xml file in /apps didn't look correct.

I hope this helps somebody.